# How to prevent direct access to files from browser?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, security

I am working on a CI Application.

Now I Have a folder in my project called **base_ini**, in which I have some config files. I want to secure this file, so no can can view its content directly from browser.

So I tried this two ways:

1. Put an **index.html** saying that **Directory access is forbidden**.
2. I put a **.htaccess** file in that folder with **Deny from all**

If I pass this in URl : www.example.com/base_ini I do get proper error message.
But still if from browser I pass this path **www.example.com/base_ini/default.ini** then I can view its content.

How can I stop this access?

Comment: default.ini have client side code you can't protract it from user. there is only one method to protract these create the routs by these files names and redirect user to somewhere else.

Comment: my iOS and Android clients have to access this and my php script other than that i don't want any other way to view this file

Comment: add this line in your htaccess  Options -Indexes

Comment: i added this as well and it working for now <Files ~ "\.ini$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files> i have to check with my android and ios clients

Comment: Read: [How to securely allow users to upload files](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files). The answer is: Don't put them in your web root to begin with.

Comment: Yes thank you @ScottArciszewski in my root i have my project folder in that i have kept those files

Comment: The simple solution is `mv /var/www/myprojectname/files /var/www/files` and update your code in accordance to this new directory schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put below line in your htaccess file and put that file at www.example.com/base_ini/ (path)

Options -Indexes